# functionality of django blog

Tags: django, django-models, blogs

Can any one please explain me the functionality of this blog APP, https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps

What is category and why is that a Mamy to Many field with POSt what is the concept of this blog App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can categorize your blog posts

For example you can create categories: Life, Career, Hobby
And then you can associate the blog posts to the categories (many of them)

You can look at my blog, to understand what I mean (categories are on the right):

http://b-fil.com/blog/

Comment: @ShadowCloud:I had looked at your post do u mean to say that in the page u posted for a particular post there could be many categories  if so what is the use of it..

Comment: I think it has been done for flessibility, if you don't like to put a post under many categories, just select only one =) you can also specify no categories at all I think

Comment: @ShadowCloud:But i want to know what is the concept of a blog.Is it that a user starts on a post and other reply??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog What you described is a forum, not a blog.. a blog is to write an entry that can be read and commented by the visitors of your blog..

Comment: @shadowcloud:But in the link i posted if u look at the models where would the other users reply what field is it in the models.py..

Comment: I'm using 'django.contrib.comments' application for managing comments on my blog posts, the app is part of the contrib package, so it's bundled with django, it is not related to a particular object, comments can be related to every model being part of your website, that is why it is not specified on the Post model of django-basic-blog app